# Does anyone experiencing freezing during iPhone app launching or closing?

Tags: iphone, ios4

App freezes, and the device freezes sometime during launching or closing. This happens especially to the app developed and installed using Xcode. Can anyone explain what's going on, if it's iOS 4 Gold Beta specific issue, or a generic task must be handled by a developer?

Answer (score 0):

Use the Debugger, Console and `NSLog()` statements to track the progress of your application throughout its life. This will help you track the bug in your application.

Comment: Also, run Instruments and / or Shark to see if there's a calculation chewing up a lot of CPU time or a lock contention issue.